# How can I fix my extensions path, or why aren't they working when downloaded?

Tags: python, path

I'm a super new "coder" so please explain like I'm five!I am using linux with ubuntu, which I have never used before also.

I'm trying to follow this youtube tutorial for image processing using VScode  https://www.google.com/search?q=image+processing+python+tutorial&oq=image+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j35i39l2j0i433i512j0i131i433i512l5j0i433i512.2303j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=_e4CWYoLFBLOP0PEP5oeM2AQ16

this is where I'm at in the tutorial:

```
from keras.datasets import mnist

import numpy as np

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

I needed to download keras, numpy, and matplotlib. I did this using the pip download for keras and numpy, and yesterday afternoon I was getting a "cannot be resolved Pylance" error. However, when I logged on today I was not getting that error for keras or numpy but still matplotlib. So I went and downloaded the matplotlib extension on the extensions page in vscode. Now, all three lines are coming up with no errors in the workspace but when I run it, an error pops up:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)

/home/joshua/Desktop/Andrea/VS Code Practice/Test/model_dev.ipynb Cell 1' in <cell line: 1>()

----> 1 from keras.datasets import mnist

---> 21 from tensorflow.python import tf2

     22 from keras import distribute

     24 from keras import models

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'
```

There is no directory found for keras or another extension called tensorflow, which I then downloaded in the vscode extensions window. I have opened/closed vscode, restarted the window from the command line, and rebooted the computer.

I think this is me not understanding paths- I did get a warning that "/home/joshua/.local/bin" is not part of the path for each of these. I have tried in the settings to input

```
"terminal.integrated.env.linux": {
        "PATH": "/home/joshua/.local/bin: ${env:PATH}"
    },
    "python.analysis.stubPath": "/home/joshua/.local/bin
```

and methods to add a path in the command line, like:

```
PATH=$PATH:$HOME/home/joshua/.local/bin
```

still if I go to the extensions page within VScode, they are showing as downloaded.

If I need to find these in their downloaded filepath, I'm not sure how to go about that, I have found a couple methods (of course did not save that and cannot find the same ones) but mostly I am unsure what to call each extension when telling the computer to search for it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue by downloading anaconda and nvidia, as well as some updates, which allowed me to successfully download all of the problematic extensions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).